# Is it mandatory to update my app with new Ad unit ID after moving form legacy Admob to new Admob account

Tags: android, admob, payment

I've upgraded from old legacy `Admob` account to new Admob. In the "What to do next" section of the new `Admob` account , there is a guide : Replace legacy ad unit IDs with new IDs https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/6025739?hl=en .

I want to know that whether it is mandatory to update my apps with new Ad unit ID (of new `Admob`) instead of using Legacy Publisher ID(of legacy `Admob`) in my apps.

What happens if i don't update my app ?

Will the earnings(after upgrading to new `Admob`) be shown in the new `Admob` when i'm using Legacy Publisher ID(of legacy `Admob`) in my apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not mandatory (at least not yet).

Your earnings will be shown in the new Admob dashboard.

But as with all change it is better to be proactive than to find yourself so far behind as to be unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Good Thing is, You can grab all features of mediation along with Google Play Services. Admob does n't insist to change Id from Legacy to new version. Bad, An annoying warning message will be shown on your dashboard.